# Validar campos de formulario

Tags: validación

Espero se encuentren bien, estoy realizando un proyecto de una fundación pero no se mucho del tema de formularios web, los correos que llegan están llegando sin información y me han informado que no tengo validación de campos.
Envío el código que tengo haber si alguien puede colaborarme, muchísimas gracias de antemano.

**Html**

```
                    <div class="column_2">

                        <form action="mail.php" method="post" id="distributor_form">

                            <div class="message hidden">

                                <p class="copy">Oh no! The information provided is not valid.<br>Please try again.</p>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-field">

                                <label for="company" class="label">Empresa / Negocio</label><br>

                                <input type="text" name="empresa" id="company" class="input required">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-field">

                                <label for="name" class="label">Tu Nombre</label><br>

                                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="name" class="input required">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-field">

                                <label for="email" class="label">Tu e-Mail</label><br>

                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input required">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-field">

                                <label for="phone" class="label">Número Telefónico</label><br>

                                <input type="text" name="tel" id="phone" class="input required">

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-field">

                                <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" style="

background-color: #9E1E1E;

color: #F9B009;

cursor: pointer;

border: none;

padding: 7px 14px;

font-size: 23px;

border-radius: 6px;

margin: 8px 2px;

float: right;
```

" >

```
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$tel=$_POST['tel'];
$empresa=$_POST['empresa'];




$cadena=
"Su Nombre es: ".$nombre."\n".
 "Su Email es: ".$email."\n".
"Su Teléfono es: ".$tel."\n".
"Empresa: ".$empresa."\n".
"\n";
$mail="info@agropaucol.com";
$asunto="Contacto Web Agropaucol ";

    $destino=("$mail");
if(mail($destino,$asunto,$cadena,"From: <$email>")){
    echo "<script>alert('¡Gracias por contactar con nosotros! Su solicitud ha sido enviada, le atenderemos lo antes posible.');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.html'; </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('ha ocurrido un error');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.html'; </script>";
}
}else{
echo "<script>alert('No hay envio de datos');</script>";
echo "<script>window.location='index.html'; </script>";
 }
```

?>

Mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es siempre validar por los dos lados, (Cliente, Servidor).
Debes de realizar las validaciones si estas en PHP desde tu lenguaje y por otro lado es bueno que tengas también con JavaScript.

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo puedes validar en JS un campo de texto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Img/Favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- FORMULARIO A VALIDAR -->
    <form action="" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return ValidacionCampos();">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="Nombre" id="Nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre">
        <br>
        <label>Teléfono</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="Nums" placeholder="Ingrese su telefono">
        <br>
        <label>Correo</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su E-mail">
        <br>
        <label>Ingrese contraseña</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="contraseña1" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña">
        <br>
        <label>Ingrese contraseña nuevamente</label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="contraseña2" placeholder="nuevamente ingrese su contraseña">
        <br>
        <label>Enviar Datos</label><br>
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>


    <!-- VALIDACIONES CON JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script>
        function ValidacionCampos() {
            let nombre, contraseña1, contraseña2, Nums, correo; // INICIALIZANDO UNA VARIABLE

            correo = document.getElementById('correo').value; // OBTENER EL ID DEL CAMPO HTML 
            Nums = document.getElementById('Nums').value; // OBTENER EL ID DEL CAMPO HTML 
            nombre = document.getElementById('Nombre').value; // OBTENER EL ID DEL CAMPO HTML 
            contraseña1 = document.getElementById('contraseña1').value; // OBTENER EL ID DEL CAMPO HTML 
            contraseña2 = document.getElementById('contraseña2').value; // OBTENER EL ID DEL CAMPO HTML 

            expresion =
                /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            letras = /^[A-Za-z\_\-\.\s\xF1\xD1]+$/;

            // CAMPOS EN BLANCO
            if (nombre === "" || Nums === "" || correo === "" || contraseña1 === "" || contraseña2 === "") {
                alert("No pueden haber campos en blanco");
                return false;
            }

            // SOLO LETRAS 
            else if (!letras.test(nombre)) {
                alert("El Nombre  solo pueden ser letras");
                return false;
            }

            // SOLO NÙMEROS
            else if (isNaN(Nums)) //ISNAN PERMITE VALIDAR SOLO NÙMEROS EN JAVASCRIPT
            {
                alert("El Nùmero de telèfono solo pueden ser números");
                return false;
            }

            // VALIDAR UN EMAIL
            else if (!expresion.test(correo)) {
                alert("El correo electronico no es correcto");
                return false;
            }

            // SI SON DIFERENTES UNO DEL OTRO
            else if (contraseña1 != contraseña2) {
                alert("las contraseñas no son iguales");
                return false;
            }

            // DEFINIR UN TAMAÑO
            else if (nombre.length > 15) {
                alert("El nombre no debe superar los 15 caracteres");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

La expresión regular llamada expresión valida un correo electrónico correctamente y la de letras valida que no se ingresen números en el campo.

Luego de eso en tu Button tipo submit llama un evento de JS OnClick y traes la función donde están todas las validaciones.

espero te sirvan.

Comment: y como podria validar el correo sin usar una exprecion regular??

Comment: Normalmente siempre se emplea una expresión regular, porque esta permite evitar que su usuario ingrese parametros como un espacio, tildes, entre otros. Por html en el Input puedes usar el atributo REQUIRED que validara que el correo contenga almenos un @ pero no es lo indicado y mas recomendado.